# Removing duplicates in SQL left join

Tags: sql, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates of my results from left join.
Because there are several types of 'schnapp's in a store, the result is listing many of same stores.
I just want to see if a store carries any type of 'schnapp's.
How would I get distinct store names?

Below is what I've written:

```
SELECT stores.name, sales.category_name
FROM stores LEFT JOIN
     sales
     ON sales.store = stores.store
WHERE category_name ILIKE '%schnapp%'
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sample data and expected result please.

Comment: Try SELECT DISTINCT... http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-distinct/

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to see if a store carries any type of 'schnapp's. How would I get distinct store names?

One simple method is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT st.name
FROM stores st LEFT JOIN
     sales s
     ON s.store = st.store
WHERE s.category_name ILIKE '%schnapp%';
```

A better method is `exists`:

```
select st.*
from stores st
where exists (select 1
              from sales s
              where s.store = st.store and
                    s.category_name ilike '%schnapp%'
             );
```

This avoids the outer aggregation, so it is likely to be faster.

Comment: It worked!!! I didn't realize that there was no need to include sales.category_name in SELECT.... Very new to SQL haha. Thank you so muchhh :)